# self join mysql complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, self-join

I have a table named `call_charges` it has following data in it.
[image]

I need to get all un-paid payments whose payment retries is also unpaid.

i.e rows which has `transaction_bid` not null and `is_paid` 0, will return records with `id` 6 and 10.
But `id` 6 has has a paid retry(`id` 12, with `retry_id` 6 and `is_paid` 1), so row with `id` 6 should not be there in the result.

I have tried with:

```
SELECT `call_charges`.* FROM `call_charges` LEFT JOIN `call_charges` AS 
`retries_call_charges` ON `retries_call_charges`.`retry_id` = `call_charges`.`id`
WHERE `call_charges`.`is_paid` = 0 AND (`call_charges`.`transaction_bid` IS NOT NULL 
AND `call_charges`.`retry_id` IS NULL)
```

But it returns both the rows with `id` 6 and 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SELECT `call_charges`.* FROM `call_charges` LEFT JOIN `call_charges` AS 
`retries_call_charges` ON `retries_call_charges`.`retry_id` = `call_charges`.`id` run this query and see what you get, then create your WHERE based on the data.

Comment: hey you wants the 10th one only...

Comment: Yes, the 10th one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT c1.id
FROM call_charges c1
LEFT JOIN call_charges c2
ON c1.id = c2.retry_id AND c2.is_paid = 1
WHERE c1.transaction_bid IS NOT NULL
AND c1.is_paid = 0
AND c2.id IS NULL
AND c1.retry_id IS NULL
```

**Working Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29549/13

`c2.id` could be null because a `LEFT JOIN` has been used. When `c1.id` does not match `c2.retry_id` then `c2.id` will be NULL.

Comment: It worked, please explain what is the meaning of `c2.id IS NUL`? `id` is a primary key and it is not null for any record.

Comment: It does not work, if 12th row has is_paid 0 then it should return both 6th and 10th row, but it return only 10th row.

Comment: @shweta fixed and updated the answer above (including fiddle). By the way, last AND condition may or may not be required in your condition.